# Взлететь vs Улететь

Tags: грамматика, приставки

What's the difference between **взлетать/взлететь** and **улетать/улететь**?

Is the first one especially for the take off of an airplane, whereas the latter one is especially for a bird flying away?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They have different meanings

**взлетать/взлететь** - to take off  - vector of motion is vertical
**улетать/улететь** -  to fly away - vector of motion is horizontal

it's possible to **взлететь** without **улетaть**

Both are applicable to planes and birds, to anything able to fly.

Comment: Just a thought: perhaps horizontal isn't an essential part of it, since a helium balloon definitely can **улететь** accidentally. Admittedly, though, pretty much everything else does fly away with some horizontal component.

Comment: _Улетать/улететь_ without _взлететь/взлетать_ is also possible.

Comment: @Nikolay Ershov i agree, i thought of the most prevalent connotation, use of `улететь` upwards one can encounter much rarer in the speech, probably because this type of flying away happens just as rarely

Answer (score 1):

That's difficult to rationalize the meaning of prefixes **"вз"** and **"у"**, almost as difficult as to explain the rationale behind **"off"** in "take **off**". But one can always try.

Let's look at **ВЗ** first:

Here are some words that use this prefix:

---

**взлететь** - take off

**вздумать** - come up with an idea

**вломать** - crack, or break something forcefully

**взбодриться** - energize oneself (that's the word Nescafe uses on their coffee in Russia)

**взбаламутить** - to distort  something intentionally, turn something peaceful into something chaotic

**взрыть** - dig the ground emotionally without any purpose (sometimes about bombs but usually about animals)

---

There is also **ВОЗ** prefix, which seems to carry the same meaning as **ВЗ** and just being another phonetic for for the latter:

---

**возмутить** - (same as взбаламутить i.e. turn something calm/still into chaotic)

**возделать** - cultivate, or precisely turn wild soil into a garden or a field

**воздеть** - raise something bravely, i.e. head, flag, but not a problem for instance

**вознамериться** - get your mind set on something (but not just having it set on something, as in other examples, the word is about a moment when something have started or got done)

**возгордиться** - start being too proud at some moment

---

Not sure if you see the pattern, but I can observe that it seems to be about applying one's energy, emotions and effort to get something done or started also implying the moment when it have happened or have started.

Now the **У** part. The usage seems very diverse, but take a look, I will show how some words with У have one meaning and next to them the same words without the У prefix having another meaning:

---

**упасть** - to fall, **пасть** - to fall

**умыть** - get washed, **мыть** - to wash

**узнать** - obtain knowledge, **знать** - to know something

**угадать** - make a correct guess, **гадать** - do guessing

**убить** - to kill, **бить** - to beat

**упрятать** - make something hidden, **прятать** - to hide

---

Now the verbs that describe some form of a movement

**улететь** - fly away, **лететь** - to fly

**уплыть** - swim away, **плыть** - to swim

**уйти** - to go away, **идти** - to go

**убежать** - run away, **бежать** - to run

---

In both cases the prefix adds the meaning of something being complete, done, rather just happening. But in the latter case it is also about the direction of the move away from the area of the mental focus at the moment of the conversation.

Interesting is how **У** behaves with the suffixes meant to emphasize that something is still happening:

---

**улетает** - in a process of flying away

**убивает** - in a process of getting something killed

**угадывала** - she was continuously making attempts to make a right guess

---

The other answer states that the difference between **взлететь** and **улететь** is about the direction, and although in this particular case it seems to be true, the real difference is that **ВЗ** is about effort and energy, and **У** is about something being finished. In practive the space ship or a coin in the well both can **улететь** (fly away) vertically and your enterprise or a startup can **взлететь** (take off) without any vertical movement in the physical world, all will be the correct usage of those words.

Again, because repeating is good, repeating is good, when you encounter **ВЗ** think of someone's effort, and when you encounter the **У** prefix think of something that finishes completely.

Ironically there is another "vertical" use for the word **улететь** to mean somebody "getting high", used both about someone daydreaming or envisioning something actively or someone using drugs.